# c# - Data won't save in my database

Tags: c#, sql, database, stored-procedures

My data won't save on my database. Instead of going into "Product has been added", it goes to "Product ID already exist" even though it's not. Here is the code:

```
private void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtNewProductID.Text == "" || txtNewProductName.Text == "" || txtNewProductPrice.Text == "" || cboNewProductCategory.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill up the form!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

        else
        {
            int prodQty = Convert.ToInt32(txtNewProductQuantity.Text);
            decimal prodPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewProductPrice.Text);

            if (!myData.AddProducts(txtNewProductID.Text, txtNewProductName.Text, prodQty, prodPrice, cboNewProductCategory.Text))
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Product has been added!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

            else
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Product ID already exist", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Retry)
                {
                    txtNewProductID.Clear();
                    txtNewProductName.Clear();
                    txtNewProductPrice.Clear();
                    txtNewProductQuantity.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code from my class library:

```
public bool AddProducts(string productID, string productName, int productQuantity, decimal productPrice, string productCategory)
    {
        bool recordFound = false;
        myCon.Open();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand saveProduct = new SqlCommand("AddProduct", myCon);
            saveProduct.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = productID;
            saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = productName;
            saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productQuantity;
            saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = productPrice;
            saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductCategory", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = productCategory;
            saveProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myCon.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            myCon.Close();
            recordFound = true;
        }

        return recordFound;
    }
```

And this is from my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddProduct]
@ProductID nvarchar(50),
@ProductName varchar(50),
@ProductQuantity int,
@ProductPrice decimal(18,2),
@ProductCategory nvarchar(50)
AS
INSERT INTO ProductsTbl
VALUES (@ProductID, @ProductName, @ProductQuantity, @ProductPrice, @ProductCategory)
RETURN 0
```

Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Note: don't swallow exceptions, as you do now!

Comment: Ugg, returning `false` to indicate `AddProducts()` succeeded is not a good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a copy paste issue here:

```
saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = productName;
saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productQuantity;
```

Instead it must be:

```
saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = productName;
saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductQuantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productQuantity;
```

By the way, don't use the `Catch` to close the connection. Instead i strongly recommend to use the `using`-statement for the connection and the command. Ensure that the connection is closed everytime this method is finished. Note that `con.Close` won't close the physical connection but it just tells the connection-pool that it's ready to be used somewhere else. Otherwise you block it, so that everytime a new connection has to be openend:

```
public bool AddProducts(string productID, string productName, int productQuantity, decimal productPrice, string productCategory)
{
    bool recordFound = false;

    try
    {
        using (var myCon = new SqlConnection("Connection-String from config-file"))
        using (var saveProduct = new SqlCommand("AddProduct", myCon))
        {
            saveProduct.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = productID;
            saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = productName;
            saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductQuantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productQuantity;
            saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = productPrice;
            saveProduct.Parameters.Add("@ProductCategory", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = productCategory;
            myCon.Open(); // will be closed implicitely at the end of the using
            saveProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) when (new[] {2627, 2601}.Contains(ex.ErrorCode))
    {
        // index constraint
        recordFound = true;
    }
    catch(Exception otherExceptions)
    {
        // log this!
        throw; // don't ignore it
    }

    return recordFound;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been so careless with it. Btw, thanks for the additional info, will try to implement it.

Comment: @Albert: you're welcome. You noticed also the additional `Catch(SqlException)`? It's a much better approach than treating all exceptions as an index constraint violation.

Comment: yeah I noticed it. So basically the other `catch` is for the exceptions and the other is for your own use? And you can also use both `catch` to show two different types of exceptions?

Comment: @Albert: the other catch is to handle all other exceptions, even `SqlExceptions` that are not constraint violations. These should be logged and the method should not treat it as normal work flow. Maybe you don't want to `throw` it, but it should definitely be noticed.